# PowerBI: New Column = Sum of value where key = X

Tags: powerbi, dax

Let's say I have a table that looks like this:

```
Human   Theme   Score
----------------------
J1      Surfing     2
J2      Eating      3
J3      Sleeping    4
J2      Eating      5
J2      Surfing     6
```

Now I want to add columns to get the total value of a theme of the humans separately. To give you an idea:

```
Jury    Theme   Score   EatingTotal SurfingTotal    SleepingTotal
------------------------------------------------------------------
J1      Surfing   2         0            2              0
J2      Eating    3         8            6              0
J3      Sleeping  4         0            0              4
J2      Eating    5         8            6              0
J2      Surfing   6         8            6              0
```

How do I get there? Is there a way in DAX to say something like

```
SurfingTotal = SUM(if table[Theme] = Surfing)
```

Still new to PowerBI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are probably several ways to do it, but this one seems to work:

```
Total Eating Measure = 

CALCULATE(
      SUM(Jury[Score]);
      ALLEXCEPT(
         Jury;
         Jury[Human]
      );
      Jury[Theme]="Eating"
) + 0
```

I've added the zero in the end, to prevent showing blank values.

[image: Example:]